# monotonicity property of a superadditive function.

Tags: functions

Suppose that a function f defined in R^+ satisfies that (i) f(x)>0 and f'(x)>0 for all x>0; (ii) f(0)=0; and (iii) f(x+y)>f(x)+f(y) for all x,y>. Does the convexity of f(x)/x imply that f(x)/x is increasing in x?